# Changing page background via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to get this to work for the past 6 hours and I am just unable to do it right. I've looked at the questions and solutions on SO as well to no avail. What am I doing horribly wrong?!?

All I have is a html5 page with no background. In my javascript code I call upon this method when the document is ready:

```
/*
 * Initializes the landing page.
 */
function initializeLanding(){
    $('body').css({
        'backround':'url("http://40.media.tumblr.com/290e7a272b492735ddf8cd968e657d05/tumblr_nhmg6xYnv41u7ns0go1_1280.jpg")'
    });
}
```

It should be something stupidly simple, and yet here I am. I've tried using single quotes, double quotes, without multiple attributes, etc. I would also much rather not use CSS or DOM properties to change the background, as I have set up way points along the page to change the background upon scrolling past them.

Also, if I call the .css() method and put in new attributes, will it overwrite all the old ones, or just the stated attributes in the latest css() call?

Update: here is where I call the function:

```
  var main = function(){                                                          
      $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();                                           
      lorem();                                                                    
      initializeLanding();                                                        
  }                                                                               
  $(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Are you actually calling the function anywhere?

Comment: Where do you call the function initializeLanding ?

Comment: have you put the `initializeLanding()` function in the `$(document).ready(function(){});` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have a spelling mistake.

backround => background.

Comment: I knew it was something stupid. It's probably time to give myself a break.

Answer (score 3):

check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/1oocaxpL/1/)

you have a spelling mistake.  replace **backround** to **background**

```
 function initializeLanding(){
    $('body').css({
    'background':'url("http://40.media.tumblr.com/290e7a272b492735ddf8cd968e657d05/tumblr_nhmg6xYnv41u7ns0go1_1280.jpg")'
    });  
  }
```

Comment: I don't know why people downvoted you so much. I would've picked your answer just fine too.

Comment: @Manoz it just delay when i am creating fiddle :). so Tonimiko understand what is wrong in code with example :)